# rails devise when account created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using rails with devise, and I want to be able to access a variable containing the time an account was created.  As far as I can tell, there's no created_at or likewise method or similar.

EDIT
There is no created_at method, I'm asking if there is any other way to determine when the user was created.  I'm assuming there is not, but I figured it's worth an ask

Comment: The user should have a `created_at` column.

Comment: Yes, User model—all models have time stamps.

Comment: This model has no timestamp.  If I call user.created_at it gives me a no such method error

Comment: Can you edit the question with your user.rb model? And also the output of the following line on console:
User.column_names

Answer (score 0):

when you create a devise model with the command line

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

let's say, for instance, your MODEL is called user... if that user model is a instance of active record, it should contain the created_at and updated_at info like all the other models

Comment: yes, definitely should be there: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/active_record/templates/migration.rb line 11 shows the timestamps being generated as expected